# How to Edit Dyanamic Lotus Notes Table

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus

[image: lotus notes instance table]

In the snippet of code with the dashed lines, I want to change the green triangle images and change the text and get into the HTML code.

It appears to be a Lotus Notes "include" snippet of code.  How do I edit the actual HTML?

I've tried a number of experiments: RMB on the dahsed lines, inside the table, Double Clicking, playing with the attributes in the panel below (clicking on Window Title, HTML Head Content, HTML Body Attributes). Nothing works.

I am new to Lotus Notes and I don't know what kind of table I just inherited in this very old file I need to change.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking at is a Form with a reserved name "$$View Template for...".  What you are calling a "table" is an Embedded View.  Specifically, it is the view named WebIndex.  Some of the things you want to change are part of the view itself, and you will have to go there to change them.  And some of them may be properties of Shared Actions that have been added to the View's action bar.  Some of them may be properties of the Embedded View control on the Form.  (It's hard to tell, because you're a little vague about what text you want to change.)

However, it's pretty clear that this is a standard view, which means that the Domino server's built-in HTML rendering is doing the bulk of the work -- that's where the green triangles come from, but since you're new to Domino you don't know what a standard view is.

So first off, I've got to tell you that your options for changing the rendering of a standard view are limited.  You would probably have to change it from a standard view to an HTML view (that's done in the View Properties dialog), and take full responsibility for generating HTML for the view, which will mean that you will have to learn about the various Domino URL formats that your HTML will have to generate.  And that goes well beyond what can be addressed in a single (or even a series) of StackOverflow questions.  It requires a fair amount of investment in learning Domino web programming (classic, pre xpages style).

Comment: Thanks Richard for answering.  In other words, you're saying it's not just as simple as opening up the view and modifying HTML and CSS, it's way more complicated?  I guess I'll leave it.  That old font is ugly. It's about 10 years old.

Comment: You can fix the font, to a certain extent. That is done in the view itsel. As Rich says, you can tell Domino to render the view as HTML, but then you need to generate the HTML yourself.
YOu could actually use jQuery to modify the output/HTML after it is rendered, I blogged about that a while back: http://blog.texasswede.com/replace-images-on-web-page-using-jquery/

It might be a good idea for you to either invest some time in learning classic Domino web development, or perhaps even hire someone who already knows it.

Comment: Yes, Karl-Henry is right.  Changing the fonts and colors are quite easy.